# Como eu faço para limitar a quantidade de caracteres em um textarea e um input usando o CSS

Tags: html, css

Boa tarde.
Eu estou fazendo uma atividade na faculdade, onde eu preciso limitar um campo de texto para 100 caracteres, mas eu tenho que usar apenas o CSS para isso.

Eu já tentei essas duas maneiras:

Exemplo 1:

```
.es1[type="text"]{
    background-color: rgb(173,234,234);
    font-weight: bolder;
    width: 20ch;
```

Exemplo 2:

```
.es1[type="text"]{
    background-color: rgb(173,234,234);
    font-weight: bolder;
    max-width: 20ch;
```

Mas, não consegui. Desde já eu agradeço ;)

Comment: Com CSS??? Isso você não vai conseguir nunca. Provavelmente você deve ter perdido alguma parte da atividade.

Comment: Comumente é usado o atributo [`input[maxlength]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) ou [`textarea[maxlength]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea). Mas CSS eu nunca tinha visto.

Comment: se utilizado `max-width: 15ch;` e `overflow: hidden;`, você consegue delimitar a quantidade de linhas para determinadas tags, como o `<p>`, mas não um campo de entrada de valores

Answer (score 4):

Se for para limitar o número de caracteres dentro do input vc pode usar `maxlength="100"` e para comportar dentro dele visualmente exatamente 100 caracteres vc pode colocar `width: 100ch`

Nesse exemplo vc pode ver, limitei em 10 caracteres apenas assim como a largura em `10ch` para ficar certinho apenas 10 caracteres de largura no `input`. ***Mas leia a observação abaixo.***

```css
.es1[type="text"]{
  width: 10ch; /* largura equivalente a 10 letras (10ch) */
  background-color: rgb(173,234,234);
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<!-- o campo só deixa digitar 10 caracteres como o maxlength -->
<input class="es1" type="text" value="1234567890" maxlength="10">
<input class="es1" type="text" value="mmmmm" maxlength="10">
```

**OBS:**

Segundo a documentação da Mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

> **CH** Representa a largura, ou mais precisamente a medida avançada, do glifo "0" (zero, o caractere Unicode U + 0030) no elemento.

Rezumindo, se vc preencher com 10 caracteres <kbd>0</kbd> vai dar certinho, mas se forem 10 letras <kbd>M</kbd> não vai caber na largura do `input`

Suporte dos browsers a unidade `CH`: https://caniuse.com/#feat=ch-unit

Answer (score 3):

Eu sempre uso direto no HTML o `maxlength`.

Fica assim, e pode usar tanto no `input` quanto no `textarea`:

```
<textarea name="mensagem" rows="7" maxlength="512" ></textarea>
```